# Error al cargar Form data c#

Tags: c#-8.0

tengo una consulta, estoy realizando un metodo para registrar usuarios y registro una imagen, lo que sucede es que cuando estoy realizando la ejecuciòn del metodo me aparece el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El metodo que estoy usando en el controller es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la logica de este metodo es la siguiente:

```
public class RegisterUserCommandHandler : 

IRequestHandler<RegisterUserCommand, AuthResponse>
   {
       private readonly UserManager<Usuario> _userManager;

       private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

       private readonly IAuthService _authService;

       public RegisterUserCommandHandler(UserManager<Usuario> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IAuthService authService)
       {
           _userManager = userManager;
           _roleManager = roleManager;
           _authService = authService;
       }


       public async Task<AuthResponse> Handle(RegisterUserCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       {
           var existUserByEmail=await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(request.Email!) is null?false:true;
           if(existUserByEmail){
               throw new BadRequestException("El email del usuario ya existe en la base de datos");
           }
           var existUserByName=await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.UserName!) is null?false:true;
           if(existUserByName){
               throw new BadRequestException("El nombre de usuario ya existe en la base de datos");
           }
           var usuario=new Usuario
           {
               Nombre=request.Nombre,
               Apellido=request.Apellido,
               Telefono=request.Telefono,
               Email=request.Email,
               UserName=request.UserName,
               AvatarUrl=request.FotoUrl
           };
           var resultado=await _userManager.CreateAsync(usuario!,request.PassWord!);
           if(resultado.Succeeded){
               await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(usuario,AppRole.GenericUser);
               var roles=await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(usuario);
               return new AuthResponse
               {
                   Id=usuario.Id,
                   Nombre=usuario.Nombre,
                   Apellido=usuario.Apellido,
                   Telefono=usuario.Telefono,
                   Email=usuario.Email,
                   Username=usuario.UserName,
                   Avatar=usuario.AvatarUrl,
                   Token=_authService.CreateToken(usuario,roles),
                   Roles=roles
               };
               
           }
           throw new Exception ("No se pudo registrar el usuario");
       }
           

   }
```

Comment: Dale un breakpoint en la línea 50 del controlador y mira si tienes todos los datos. Me late que la foto está faltando. Por cierto, bienvenido a SOes, recuerda realizar el recorrido para que veas la dinámica del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Saludos.